# How can I create a trigger in SQL Server on insert?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to create a trigger in SQL Server 2012 that activates when I insert a row into a specific table.

The trigger must insert a value in a specific column, in the same table and row I am inserting the new row into.

The trigger must only activate if a specific column in the row I am inserting does not have a value ie. null.

Let's say I am inserting into:

- Table: `car`
- Columns: `car_make | car_price | car_img`

If I provide all values in the insert:

```
car_make | car_price | car_img
```

the trigger must not activate

But, if I only insert values for 2 columns:

```
car_make | car_price
```

the `car_img` value is null, then trigger must activate and do the following:

- Insert a predefined value in the column `car_img` in the same affected row

PS. I have to use a trigger, it's for an assignment. I cannot use a default value.

Comment: You need to set a default values for all the columns in your table not a trigger for this simple requirement.

Comment: @MuhammedAli I have to use a trigger, is mandatory. It's for an assignment.

Comment: Trigger for such a simple requirement is really an over kill but anyway see my answer.

Comment: Just a side-note: if you have an `FOR INSERT` trigger, it will fire always - you cannot *selectively* let it fire (or not) depending on your data. What you *can do* is check for these conditions in the trigger code and handle the situation as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create Trigger tr_ForInserts_car
ON dbo.car
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON;


    UPDATE Car
     SET car_make = /*Your Default Value*/
     WHERE car_make IS NULL

     UPDATE Car
     SET car_price = /*Your Default Value*/
     WHERE car_price IS NULL

     UPDATE Car
     SET car_img = /*Your Default Value*/
     WHERE car_img IS NULL
END
```

**Edit**

My previous suggestion will update all the rows where corresponding column is null, to update only the column for newly insert rows try the following please

```
Create Trigger tr_ForInserts_car
ON dbo.car
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON;


     UPDATE Car
     SET Car.car_make = /*Your Default Value*/
     FROM Car INNER JOIN inserted
     ON Car.PrimaryKey = inserted.PrimaryKey
     WHERE Car.car_make IS NULL

     UPDATE Car
     SET Car.car_price = /*Your Default Value*/
     FROM Car INNER JOIN inserted
     ON Car.PrimaryKey = inserted.PrimaryKey
     WHERE Car.car_price IS NULL

     UPDATE Car
     SET Car.car_img = /*Your Default Value*/
     FROM Car INNER JOIN inserted
     ON Car.PrimaryKey = inserted.PrimaryKey
     WHERE Car.car_img IS NULL

END
```

Comment: But that'll update the **whole** table - not just the row (or rows) that are being inserted ... you would probably want to join to the `Inserted` pseudo table in some way to restrict your update to just those rows being actually inserted right now ....

Comment: @marc_s yes this is right but this is what OP wants, strange requirement but what can you say :)

Comment: @MuhammedAli I know it's a bit weird, and it doesn't make any sense, but that's the requirement in the school assignment. They just want us to use a trigger for the sake of using a trigger.

Comment: @user977150 you are right, but if it a school assignment dont you think you should be doing it your self rather then asking on stack overflow :), you will learn more that way

Comment: @marc_s have a look now I have update my answer only to deal with newly inserted rows.

Comment: A single `UPDATE` could handle multiple columns, e.g. `set Car.car_make = Coalesce( Car.car_make, @car_make_default ), Car.car_price = Coalesce( Car.car_price, @car_price_default ), ...`.

Comment: @HABO this will again update each row in the table regardless of whether its NULL or not. The result will be the same but unnecessary updates :)

Comment: @MuhammedAli Well, i can't do it myself if I can't learn it somewhere. Stackoverflow gives me more reliable and screened answers, which is much better than the random stuff you find on the internet. Stackoverflow has community of experts constantly checking if the information is correct, :-) so i guess the quality of the information is higher than searching on the internets.

Comment: @MuhammedAli - The `COALESCE` code if applied to all of the `Car` rows affected by the `INSERT`, i.e. using `where PrimaryKey in ( select PrimaryKey from inserted )` or your `inner join`, will replace any NULL values in the specified columns with the default values. Any other rows in the `Cars` table will be unaffected. The `where` clause can be used to limit the update to only rows having at least one NULL value that needs to be defaulted.

Comment: @HABO again you will end up doing unnecessary updates, think about it joining with inserted table you will get the rows back where column1 is null or column2 is null or column3 is null, right ?? now when you update all three column of that row , with the value in that column it self or in case of being null with the default value.  you will end up doing updates to the column where it is not needed.

Comment: @MuhammedAli - True, there will be unnecessary updates. If the columns use particularly large data types, participate in several indexes, and the database engine avoids optimizations then it might incur considerable overhead. OTOH, performing three separate updates will also involve some overhead. To some extent it depends on the actual data. Are NULLs common in input or quite rare? Are the nullable columns indexed? Are rows deleted often enough that the newly inserted rows represent the bulk of the rows? As you pointed out in your original comment, this isn't the way to implement defaults.